# Syncing several wallets in the same ledger with local node. (start again switching)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

Let's say you have several wallets in the same ledger (Plausible deniability set up), syncing each wallet using the GUI with my own local node, blockchain in external SSD drive, it takes 3 hours aprox, the problem is that when finish, if you switch accounts, the process starts always again??

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your image shows the blockchain is fully synced and up-to-date but the wallet is *scanning* the blockchain to find any transactions destined for your wallet.

If your wallet is saved on the same external drive, and has been scanned, opening the *same* wallet on another machine will not try to scan from block 1, it will scan from the last scanned height.